# One SQL statement for counting the records in the master table based on matching records in the detail table?

Tags: sql

I have the following master table called Master and sample data

```
ID---------------Date
1                2014-09-07
2                2014-09-07
3                2014-09-08
```

The following details table called Details

```
masterId-------------Name
1                    John Walsh
1                    John Jones
2                    John Carney
1                    Peter Lewis
3                    John Wilson
```

Now I want to find out the count of Master records (grouped on the Date column) whose corresponding details record with Name having the value "John".

I cannot figure how to write a single SQL statement for this job.

**Please note that join is needed in order to find master records for count. However, such join creates duplicate master records for count. I need to remove such duplicate records from being counted when grouping on the Date column in the Master table.

The correct results should be:

```
count:           grouped on Date column
2                2014-09-07
1                2014-09-08
```

**

Thanks and regards!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblmaster INNER JOIN tbldetails ON tblmaster.ID=tbldetails.masterId GROUP BY tblmaster.ID` something like this should do

Comment: Is the name format always `FIRSTNAME LASTNAME`? Based on textual lookups you could get stuck with `Bill Johnson` or something like that.

Comment: Does `ID` = `masterID`?

Comment: Dave, you can get duplicate records in the  master table. I need to remove these duplicates first.

Comment: Andrew, yes, the masterId refers to the ID column in the master table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes the following

- The Name field is always FirstName LastName
- You are looking once and only once for the John firstname. The search criteria would be different, pending what you need

---

```
SELECT Date, Count(*)
FROM tblmaster 
INNER JOIN tbldetails ON tblmaster.ID=tbldetails.masterId 
WHERE NAME LIKE 'John%'
GROUP BY Date, tbldetails.masterId
```

What we're doing here is using a [wilcard](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) character in our string search to say "Look for John where any characters of any length follows".

Also, here is a way to create table variables based on what we're working with

```
DECLARE @tblmaster as table(
ID  int,
[date] datetime
)

DECLARE @tbldetails as table(
masterID  int,
name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tblmaster (ID,[date])
VALUES
(1,'2014-09-07'),(2,'2014-09-07'),(3,'2014-09-08')

INSERT INTO @tbldetails(masterID, name) VALUES
(1,'John Walsh'),
(1,'John Jones'),
(2,'John Carney'),
(1,'Peter Lewis'),
(3,'John Wilson')
```

Based on all comments below, this SQL statement in it's clunky glory should do the trick.

```
SELECT date,count(t1.ID) FROM @tblmaster mainTable INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*)  as countOfAll
    FROM @tblmaster  t1
    INNER JOIN @tbldetails t2 ON t1.ID=t2.masterId 
    WHERE NAME LIKE 'John%' 
    GROUP BY id) 
as t1 on t1.ID = mainTable.id 
GROUP BY mainTable.date
```

Comment: Elias, your SQL creates duplicates in found master records. See my reply to Gordon. Thanks for chiming in!!!

Comment: @curious1 I hadn't noticed how it duplicates until you told me that, I added a little bit to the SQL, and this should fix it. Sorry about that!

Comment: Elias, this is close, but still does not get it. Here are the results from running your code: 2014-09-07 2, 
2014-09-07 1, 
2014-09-08 1. I got two entries for 2014-09-07.

Comment: @curious1 based on your dataset in the original question, and the desire to split up based on date I sort of stand my belief that is correct. Could you expand your example above and show us the exact result set you're looking for? Perhaps my confusion boils down to semantics.

Comment: @Ealis, I updated the post. Your SQL creates one duplicate for "1                    John Walsh" in the results set. Thanks for following up with me!!!

Comment: @curious1 No problem. You have a John on ID 3 as well. So you're going to have either the 3 johns (2 from ID 1 and 1 from ID 2) on 2014-09-07 and 1 John from ID 3 on 2014-09-08 OR the Johns split up on each ID. With your result set you are ignoring 1 John from somewhere.

Comment: @Ealis, when doing join, you create one duplicate for ID 1. The John for ID 3 is counted into 2014-09-08. The sum of counts from your SQL is 4 (see my early comment: 2, 1, 1), but the master table has only 3 records. Hope this helps.

Comment: Elias, thanks for posting statements to create these two tables. I already had them locally in MSSQL. What are the results of running your SQL solution? Remember the master table has only three records. Thanks!

Comment: @curious1 I posted the table variables for the sake of having them in the answer. Sorry it took so long, I posted my clunky select statement at the end there. You should find your solution with it :)

Comment: Elias, it works like charm. Is my post hard to understand? Could you please change it to make it more clear from your perspective? The other guy who provided a solution also missed the issue of duplicate records in the master table. I hope your kind help will help even more others. Many thanks!

Comment: @curious1 I don't believe it was hard to understand from a "If I really paid attention then I could have gotten it" perspective. It was just an ordinary request that Gordon and I both overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select date, count(distinct m.id)
from master m join
     details d
     on d.masterid = m.id
where name like '%John%'
group by date;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your input. Your SQL code count duplicate records caused by join. Here is the answer from your SQL:2014-09-07, 3; 2014-09-08, 1.